# the_field('user') brings all the information

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to bring the user's name to display, but using the_field('investor') keeps bringing me all of his information, here is my code:

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"><?php the_title() ;?></a></h3><br>

 /* HERE */ <h1>User</h1><p><?php the_field( 'investor' ); ?></p></br>
<h1>quantity</h1><p><? the_field( 'quantity' ); ?></p></br>
<h1>Date</h1><p><?php the_field( 'date_of_investment' ); ?></p></br><hr>
```

it keeps bringing me: user id, username, name, lastname, email, website etc etc.

How can I display only 1 specific field?

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact string you are getting? `var_dump(the_field( 'investor'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Advanced Custom Fields, right? Well, it depends on how you set up the fields. My guess is you're using the `User` field. You'll need to understand the difference between `the_field();` and `get_field();`.

`the_field();` echo's the value of the meta field and `get_field();` returns it. You'll want to use `get_field();` here.

First set it to a variable.

`$investor = get_field( 'investor' );`

Next you'll want to `var_dump( $investor );` or `print_r( $investor )`; that variable so you can see what item you want to access. You should get an array like this:

`Array
(
    [ID] => 5
    [user_firstname] => Ariel
    [user_lastname] => Smith
    [nickname] => arielsmith
    [user_nicename] => arielsmith
    [display_name] => Ariel Smith
    [user_email] => useremail@something.com
    [user_url] => 
    [user_registered] => 2014-06-05 16:48:58
    [user_description] => 
    [user_avatar] => 
)`

Now that you can see the data, all you have to do is echo the value of the key you want:

`<?php echo $investor['display_name`]; ?>`

*Side note, you can get rid of the `var_dump()` once you're done. You use it just to see the array key and their values. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_field()` method instead of `the_field()`